# How can I use 2 entities in kotlin android room?

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am trying to run it as a button event

Problem ->`>test_textview.text = db.dataclass().getAll().toString()`

There is no problem in case of one entity,
If you try to do 2, it does not work.
help me please..

```
 (Mainactivty.kt)
        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
        )
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()


    (Appdatabase.kt)
    @Database(entities = [DataClass::class, Test::class], version = 4) <-Is something strange here?
    abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase()
    {
        abstract fun dataclass() : DataClassDAO
        abstract fun test() : TestDAO

    }



    (DataClass.kt)

    @Entity
    data class DataClass(var test:String)
    {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id:Int=0
    }


    @Entity
    data class Test(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
                                         var username:String,
                                         var age:Int
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Each entity is a table. To get the data from multiple tables you need to join.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-multiple-tables